# Facebook Access Token for Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, access-token, facebook-page

I have a Facebook Page that I want to get some things from it. First thing are feeds and from what I read they are public (no need for access_token). But I want to also get the events... and they aren't public and need the access_token.

I don't want the user to login in Facebook or anything like that. I just want to push all the data I can from this only page. That's why I already discarded many examples I found here and the one at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/ , because they want the user to login or require some user action I'm not interessed.

What I want is that my Facebook Application have full authorization and access_token to push the data from this one Facebook Page that I own (admin). Is this possible? I already tried many things but nothing seems to work.

I tried clicking at this: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=150635421702954&redirect_uri=http://MY_URL/&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token&fields=access_token - changing MY_URL to my site's and it requests authorization to edit every page I own. Even not being what I want I clicked but had no access_token in return...

Comment: To get events I do this now (the access_token expires a lot): 1 - Get a token from the Graph Explorer 2 - Paste it in my code below: `var authToken = 'THE_CODE_I_GOT';`
`var feedQuery = 'graph.facebook.com/MY_PAGE_ID/feed';`
`var feedURL = feedQuery +'?access_token='+ authToken +'&callback=?'; `
`$.getJSON(feedURL,function(data){ 
`var d = data.data; for( i=0; i < d.length; i++) { d[i].message ? $("#list").append('<li>'+ d[i].message +'</li>') : ''; // lots of other stuff, you got it } });`

Comment: You can get a permanent token:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token/17234650#17234650

Answer (score 273):

1. Go to the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
2. Choose your app from the dropdown menu
3. Click "Get Access Token"
4. Choose the `manage_pages` permission (you may need the `user_events` permission too, not sure)
5. Now access the `me/accounts` connection and copy your page's `access_token`
6. Click on your page's id
7. Add the page's `access_token` to the GET fields
8. Call the connection you want (e.g.: `PAGE_ID/events`)

Comment: By doing this I'm able to call connections on all my pages by using a page token of only one of them. Isn't this wrong? Is there a way to get a token for just one specific page that doesn't work on the other pages?

Comment: I've climb mountains and swim oceans just seek for this answer. Thank you.

Comment: This process doesn't work anymore as the access token generated expires when you log out for whatever reason.

Comment: @coneybeare, please refer to this document on how to extend the [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/#pagetokens)

Comment: I am not able to see the 3 rd point, that is (Get Access Token). So can you please tell me the process, to get token, and active it out.?

Comment: I keep getting an empty result. Does it make a difference if it is an app page?

Comment: As I wanted to say thank you I also want to add that this seems to be the only (at last one i found) way to obtain page access token.

Comment: This used to work for me but doesn't after April 30th.

Comment: @Tony, what doesn't work? what have you tried? and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: get a specific page public posts without user login using my app access token

Comment: @Tony, this should work for public posts, try this on [cocacola/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=cocacola%2Ffeed&). Select your app from a dropdown, and then "Get App Token" and test.

Comment: I dont have a app for that page, so used a different add_id and secret with this pages auth token and got this "Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument"

Comment: @ifaour tnanx a lot for your answer!

Comment: Hi. can i add a page post with user access token who is admin of the page? please help me

Comment: There is a way to make the token never to expire. Check this answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39182923/4171578

Comment: Sure, but how do I get ONE page's access token? At the moment, our app manages hundreds of pages. Using this method, we must make numerous requests until we get the access token for the right business.

Comment: This does not work anymore, seems that there is not a way to publish to your own page with an api now.

Comment: Anyone have recently achieved this? I'm looking for this. Please help.

Comment: I do not feel people are using facebook that much like before, any how they should provide simple solutions to access at least page likes

Comment: a programmatic approach would have served better. This only helps for testing the API calls, but the real issue is how to do it with code.

Answer (score 16):

See here if you want to grant a Facebook App permanent access to a page (even when you / the app owner are logged out):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

"An App Access Token **does not expire** unless you refresh the application secret through your app settings."

Comment: This does not help with getting events for a restricted page.

Comment: Is that still true?!

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for this is good if not a little difficult to find.

[Facebook Graph API - Page Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens)

After initializing node's [fbgraph](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph), you can run:

```
var facebookAccountID = yourAccountIdHere 

graph
.setOptions(options)
.get(facebookAccountId + "/accounts", function(err, res) {
  console.log(res); 
});
```

and receive a JSON response with the token you want to grab, located at:

```
res.data[0].access_token
```

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to retrieve the Page access token from Graph API Explorer, but I did not have the option to select the Page.

It turns out that I was not an admin of the page. I was an admin of the Facebook App, and the App had access to the Facebook page, enabling me to access the page as well. This caused the confusion and chaos.