# Post to a page non related to the app or user using J-SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

I've created an Facebook web app that posts to the users wall successfully however I also want to post to a Facebook page at the same time. How do I link my App to this Facebook page so I can post to the Facebook Pages wall ass well... Really been searching everywhere and come up empty handed...

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic "post on the page wall everytime a user posts something". You will have to do this manually. So, its a two step process

1. Post on the users wall, which will require a user `access_token`
2. [Post on the page wall](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed), which will require a separate page
   access_token. I'm assuming you administer this page. Follow the
   steps listed here to get that `access_token`: [Facebook Access Token for Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages) This must be done completed server-side to prevent disclosing the access_token. So an AJAX call would be required.

Comment: Should “J-SDK” in the title actually mean the JavaScript SDK – then using the page access token should be out of the question, cause every user could steal it if it gets exposed client-side.