# Fb Graph API - want to publish without manually logging each time using Java

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I logged-in to facebook manually, creating accesstoken, logged out.

Tried to publish in my timeline using my java app, I got

```
java.lang.Exception: {"error":{"message":"Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"error_subcode":467}}
```

I've ticked the check box for `publish_stream` and `offline_access` at least while creating access token.

How could I publish in my timeline without getting logged manually each time.

Comment: There is no more offline_access. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

The `offline_access` is deprecated.
The most easy way is to use page token because this is an unlimited session token.
See there how to get it : [Facebook Access Token for Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages)