# OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-access-token

I have followed the steps from.

[Facebook Access Token for Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages)

And generated a page access token, then used the following code

```
<?php
include 'includes/facebook.php';
$app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$page_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$my_url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXX.com";
$page_access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";

//Create the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

//Write to the Page wall
try {
    $attachment = array(
                'access_token' => $page_access_token,
                'message'=> "Hello World"
        );

   $result = $facebook->api('page_id/feed', 'post',  $attachment);

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
echo $e;
}

?>
```

It works for the first time but whenever the admin logged out, it's showing the error.

"OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out."

I tried a lot of suggestions but failed.

Answer (score -1):

Try and replace

```
'page_id/feed'
```

with

```
$page_id.'/feed'
```

this should provide facebook api with correct destination page id