# subscribe realtime updates for a page events fails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I am tring to get real-time update for page events, I followed steps described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0 doesn't work for me.

[image: to verify the user subscriptions]

How to get facebook realtime update response when page owner creates any event ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: there is no response from facebook API, when facebook-page admin creates an event.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages