# Querying the photos of a facebook page with age restriction

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am the administrator of a Facebook page which needs to have an age restriction of 17+ on it.
On my website, I am making some Graph API queries, like querying photo albums and linking to them on Facebook. I am using the PHP Facebook API.

I can't seem to get to grips around the page access tokens and when they expire and when not. 
I tried to follow this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages), which was highly voted, but it isn't clear what you do with the first `access_token` after you copy it. I am not sure if this is even valid any more.

I tried to access the page using the access token I get when I do `me/accounts` in Graph Explorer and it works, but after some time it expires and I get an exception that the token expired. I need something that stays working and doesn't expire and need me to go in and update it.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$fbconfig = array();
$fbconfig['appId'] = DEF_APP_ID;
$fbconfig['secret'] = DEF_APP_SECRET;
$fbconfig['fileUpload'] = false; 

Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;

$facebook = new Facebook($fbconfig);

//I am not sure if the following is the right way
$facebook->setAccessToken(DEF_ACCESS_TOKEN);  
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();

...

try
{
    $albums_resp = $facebook->api('/'.$id.'/albums','GET'); 
    ...
}
catch (FacebookApiException $ex)
{
    error_log($ex); 
}
```

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

Comment: @rjdown Those instructions aren't even valid any more.

Comment: No I am not. Step 2 and 3 aren't even possible, they aren't there any more in the app settings.

Comment: Yes, they are. Add a website as per the docs that you should probably read

Comment: I already have an app, and it has the site URL in it. There is nowhere that says 'Website with Facebook Login' on the settings page. Could be I am already past step 2, if the URL is the only thing I need. Step 3 says 'still in settings go to Permissions'. There is no Permissions link anywhere in the settings screen, I checked the Basic and Advanced tabs. I tried to follow the (utterly confusing) instructions here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens, but I just got tokens that expire after I log out or after an hour or so. Maybe I am doing something wrong in PHP.