# facebook api request with meteor.js

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

First of all i want to make a functional call on facebook API using meteor and so far my attempt is this :

```
var link = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me"
var arguments = {
  headers: {"User-Agent": "Meteor/1.0"},
  params: {
    "access_token":  "CAAXbhZBRfBXcBAG6NjC6rG505UiVKUzP9xLc94jgARcs3tw6mdgaNWmbsOFv59SmkyrGZCU2cjOqSiJ02knmKXRMe71dZCTiyOhvx40FAm6x1RwSKTbtSFunVeWVhgcuoaNNz8xIBZAbOAWFsHo5pSbnNS3ZAZAadhrmqi1hcC5EzujI9KNZBD7TOuqUBBvV4gZD",
}
};
HTTP.call('GET',link,arguments,function(error,response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

The access token used is the one i got from the graph api explorer someone in another post mentioned ([Facebook Access Token for Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages)).
Any ideas on why it's not working?

EDIT: was missing a protocol on the link, thanks! ( this question can be closed)

Comment: what is your problem? to improve for what?

Comment: you may want to post this here instead, if you want someone to look at your code and get tips to improve it: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @webdeb it doenst work atm and i dont know why

Comment: use a protocol in your `link = 'http..``

Comment: @webdeb damn it was that "little" detal that i was missing, it's working now cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the protocol in link

```
var link = "http(s)://..."
```