# Facebook Graph API: GET semi-restricted page events without being linked to a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a simple website for a small community-run night club. I'm trying to find the simplest way to get their Page's Events without creating tokens that are based on my User. I'm creating a server-side app (django/flask) that can just pull that data periodically. I don't need any write permissions, just reads of public data. I normally would be able to do this with any App Token if the Page is public, but I can't with this one because the page is 21+ so there seem to be restrictions. I've found some solutions like [stackoverflow.com/a/8235011/1707152](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8235011/1707152), but they all seem to be dependent on a User. I don't want to include any of my User info, or create any tokens attached to my personal account just to get this data. I want to create this app for them, and be able to hand it off to the next developer without needing any of my credentials. I also don't think that they should have to give my User permissions to their Page for me to work on this. I'd like to tell them "make a developer account, create an app, give that app permissions to your Page, then send me the App ID/Secret", that way they don't have to trust my User with anything.

Is it possible for a Page to create/give an App permissions to view its public content (though the web interface)? Alternatively, can I get a permanent Page Token without that token being linked to a User? Any solution that is dependent on my User account seems wrong to me.

Comment: There is no other solution that using a User access token or a Page access token from an admin of the page. So have them create an app. Then go to the admin page of your app and they are asked to logged in. Then your app gets a page access token from them and uses that

Comment: I'm not quite following. How can my App get a Page Access Token? I don't see anything on the App Dashboard that refers to any Pages.

Comment: You read the documentation for access tokens. It explains it

Comment: Could you provide a link? I've read the docs and I don't see anything about Page Access Tokens  being obtained through an App (instead of a user).

Comment: You can't. You need to create it from a user access token of course