# Facebook php sdk api not returning geo targeted posts

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, geotargetting

I already have the facebook/graph-sdk v5.4.4 up and running.

I noticed that posts that were configured to only appear in some country or for users with certain languages were not appearing in the list return by the api.

How do I make them appear in the listing? Where can I get help with this? I went there https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/api/5.0.0 and I could not find anything with relation of my problem.

Ideally I would like to be able to send the user language and country to the request so the api sends back the pre-filtered list so I don't have to filter it on my end.

Comment: You’re looking in the wrong place. Your question concerns the Graph API, not a specific SDK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed#read // To read any page posts that are targeted to specific audiences, you need to use a user access token for a user that can see the post, or a page access token.

Comment: To get a page access token, this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages