# How to write a post on facebook using python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have tried with a sample code that I found on google..

```
import facebook

def main():
   # Fill in the values noted in previous steps here
    cfg = {
    "page_id"      : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",  # Step 1
    "access_token" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   # Step 3
    }

    api = get_api(cfg)
    msg = "Hello, world!"
    status = api.put_wall_post(msg)

def get_api(cfg):
     graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cfg['access_token'])
     # Get page token to post as the page. You can skip 
     # the following if you want to post as yourself. 
     resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')
     page_access_token = None
    for page in resp['data']:
        if page['id'] == cfg['page_id']:
            page_access_token = page['access_token']
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
    return graph

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

But I am getting this error:

> AssertionError: Write operations require an access token on line  `status = api.put_wall_post(msg)`.

Can some one help me in solving the issue?

[image: images]

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Comment: just some links to get you started. you should hit the official docs first.

Answer (score 5):

To write a post to facebook using python.we need access_token for it.

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token="XXXXXXXX")
print graph
#to post to your wall
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="Posting on my wall1!")
#to get your posts/feed
feed = graph.get_connections("me", "feed")
post = feed["data"]
print post
#to put comments for particular post id
graph.put_object(post["id"], "comments", message="First!")
```

Comment: Could you do an example like this putting an object to one of the pages managed by the user ?

Answer (score 2):

Hope, the above code works fine if you provide Page Id and Access Token.
Please follow below steps to get the access token and page Id.

1. Go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

2.Choose your app from the dropdown menu

3.Click "Get Access Token"

4.Choose the manage_pages permission (you may need the user_events permission too, not sure)

5.Now access the me/accounts connection and copy your page's access_token

6.Click on your page's id

7.Add the page's access_token to the GET fields

8.Call the connection you want (e.g.: PAGE_ID/events)

This topic was already discussed in [Facebook Access Token for Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231877/facebook-access-token-for-pages)

Comment: Iam able to get acees token but failed to get page's id..please tell me how to get it on the screen @sandeep kumar

Comment: To access your Facebook's Page ID:
1.Open your Facebook page.
2.Click the About tab.
3.Scroll down to the bottom of the Page Info section.
4.Next to Facebook Page ID, you can find your page ID.

Comment: I didnt find any page id in my facebook page

Comment: find out about your page id with the graph api explorer then. you just need to make a call to the page name (it´s in the url).

Answer (score 1):

Verified as of 2020 March:

```
!pip install facebook-sdk==2.0.0
```

then:

```
import facebook

def main():
   # Fill in the values noted in previous steps here
   cfg = {
   "page_id"      : "1xxxxx48480xxxx",  # Step 1
   "access_token" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxnp3QApxv12gjGnV99BNnhxxxxxxxxxx"   # Step 3
    }

    api = get_api(cfg)
    msg = "Hello, world!"
    status = api.put_wall_post(msg)

def get_api(cfg):

    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cfg['access_token'])
    resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')
    page_access_token = None
    for page in resp['data']:
    if page['id'] == cfg['page_id']:
        page_access_token = page['access_token']
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
    return graph

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

Considering the permissions : We need     manage_pages
    publish_pages permissions.

**page id** you can find at the bottom of the about section of your page.

Comment: Hi, do you have verified your accout as individual developer or company for your facebook app review?

Comment: I have registered as an individual developer.

Comment: thank you.so... for individual dev, no restriction about manage_pages and publish_pages?

Comment: I'm getting the below error any idea?
Seems to me like Facebook doesn't want us to develop on this API isn't?
It gets not so easy.

 status = api.put_wall_post(msg)
  File "C:\Users\SG0216333\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\riverEnv\lib\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 163, in put_wall_post
    **attachment)
  File "C:\Users\SG0216333\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\riverEnv\lib\site-packages\facebook\__init__.py", line 140, in put_object
    assert self.access_token, "Write operations require an access token"

Comment: I see that this module hasn't been updated since 2018. https://github.com/sns-sdks/python-facebook seems to be more modern but I haven't tried it yet.